# change a m-file matlab into mathematica

Tags: matlab, wolfram-mathematica

I've written a matlab m-file to draw a double integral as below. Does everybody can show me its equivalent in mathematica???

```
tetha = pi/4;
lamb = -1;
h = 4;
tetha0 = 0;
syms x y l

n = [h.*((cos(tetha)).^2)./sin(tetha); h.*abs(cos(tetha)); 0];
ft = ((tetha - pi/2)./sin(tetha)).^4;
Rt = [cos(tetha) -sin(tetha); sin(tetha) cos(tetha)];
zt = [cos(tetha0) -sin(tetha0); sin(tetha0) cos(tetha0)];
lt = [x;y];

integrand = @(x,y)(ft.*h.*((abs(cos(tetha)).*      (x.*cos(tetha)-y.*sin(tetha)))-((cos(tetha)).^2/sin(tetha)).*(x.*sin(tetha)+y.*cos(tetha))));
PhiHat = @(a,b)(dblquad(integrand,0,a,0,b));
ezsurfc(PhiHat,[0,5,0,5])
```

Comment: It would be easier to write your Mathematica for you if you showed us the original equation(s).  Right now you're kind of asking us to first derive those equations from the Matlab, then re-implement them in Mathematica.  Personally I'm not going to do either; you'll generally get better answers here on SO if you show that you have made a good start on your own problem.

Comment: It's simplicity itself that deriving some matrix productions are not very complicated neither in matlab not mathematica!
My problem is how to draw a double integral when the variables are located in the bounds of the integral not under its operator!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: I think what @High Performance Mark means is that for those of us that are not avid users of Matlab, it will be hard to make the translation to Mathematica. If you provide the original equations we don't need your Matlab implementation. I, for one, know perfectly well how to do double integrals with or without bounds in Mathematica, but have no clue concerning the meaning of this @(a,b) piece of Matlab code.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries I think `f = @(x, y) ....` is just a way to define a pure function in Matlab.

Comment: @heike I thought so much, but guessing wouldn't be the best basis for an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you go (only minimal changes made), but you'll have to do your homework to understand function definitions, integration, plotting etc. in Mathematica. Also, this is not idiomatic Mathematica, but let's not go there...

```
tetha=Pi/4;
lamb=-1;
h=4;
tetha0=0;

n={h*((Cos[tetha])^2)/Sin[tetha],h*Abs[Cos[tetha]],0};
ft=((tetha-Pi/2)/Sin[tetha])^4;
Rt={{Cos[tetha], -Sin[tetha]}, {Sin[tetha], Cos[tetha]}};
zt={{Cos[tetha0], -Sin[tetha0]}, {Sin[tetha0], Cos[tetha0]}};

integrand[x_,y_]:= (ft*h*((Abs[Cos[tetha]]*(x*Cos[tetha]-y*Sin[tetha]))-((Cos[tetha])^2/Sin[tetha])*(x*Sin[tetha]+y*Cos[tetha])));
PhiHat[a_,b_]:=NIntegrate[integrand[x,y],{x,0,a},{y,0,b}];
Plot3D[PhiHat[x,y],{x,0,5},{y,0,5}]
```

[image]

Comment: I think `Rt` should be `{{Cos[tetha], -Sin[tetha]}, {Sin[tetha], Cos[tetha]}}` (and similar for `zt`).

Comment: Yep, you're right. MATLAB takes both `,` and space as delimiters, and I missed it because when I copied it to Mathematica, the FE added its own spacing and padding...

Comment: Thank you very much dear yoda!!!
Unfortunately I've not yet been fluent on mathematica syntax but I try to be better!!!